# How to save many results in the same file.mat?

Tags: octave

I have some tests, the result of each test must be saved in .mat file.
For example:

```
funcation test (test)

if     test1
       results1
       Matrix(i_row)=results1
              save ('test.mat','Matrix')
elseif test2
       results2
       Matrix(i_row)=results2
              save ('test.mat','Matrix')
elseif test3
     results3
     Matrix(i_row)=results3
              save ('test.mat','Matrix')
end
end
```

I want to find in test.mat file the three matrix, however when I test my function i just found one matrix, 
could you please help me?

Comment: You have to store your results in an appropriate data type (a NxM matrix, a Cell...) and save this. You can't have one variable 'Matrix' which different scalar values.

Comment: @Andy, could you give me an exemple please?

Comment: Can you create a MCVE or describe better what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't worded properly, but if what you're asking is why doesn't it save all three results but it only saves the first one, then it's because you're using `elseif`.

If you want all 3 tests to run, just use `if ... end` for each test.